# SQL queries from 2 table

Tags: mysql

I got 2 tables; product table have these columns:

```
id, name_product, producer_id, number_product
```

and producer table:

```
id, producer_name
```

I must display producer name with name of product, if the producer have no product he should be omitted.

I tried this query

```
SELECT producer_name, name_product FROM product, producer WHERE name_product = producer_id
```

for some reason , it s return empty column, there is no error.

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you're matching the wrong columns. Whenever you say "WHERE" you typically match the common data items.

```
name_product and producer_id
```

sound different

Answer (score 1):

You need to [join](http://mysqljoin.com/joins/inner-join-tutorial/) your tables

```
SELECT
  prd.producer_name,
  p.name_product
FROM product p
INNER JOIN producer prd ON p.producer_id = prd.id
```

Comment: +1, but the OP does have an implicit join, although on the wrong condition.

Comment: Isn't `SELECT
  producer_name,
  name_product` should be `SELECT
  prd.producer_name,
  p.name_product`

Answer (score 1):

What about this??

```
SELECT t2.producer_name, t1.name_product FROM product t1
JOIN producer t2
ON t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t1.name_product = t2.producer_id
```